# Rails turbolink and trouble with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a problem with date turbolink callbacks. I want create fade effect on change pages.
I tried this code:

```
$(document).on 'page:fetch', ->
  $('#content').fadeOut 'slow'

$(document).on 'page:restore', ->
  $('#content').fadeIn 'slow'
```

But 'page:restore' doesn't fire and when 'page:fetch' happends page abruptly refresh with new content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
$(function() {
 initPage();
});
$(window).bind('page:load', function() {
 initPage();
})

// When turbolink execute
function initPage(){        
  //Code here 
}
```